# Setting file permissions so my Laravel command / cron task can read and write to my FTP folder

Tags: linux, permissions, cron

I have an ftp folder that I created working through a guide to allow one specific user. I have since run a few chmod commands and may have changed this but the FTP user was created in a way so they should only access the one directory.

This is the folder:

```
drwxrwxrwx 2 myftpuser myftpuser 110592 Aug 30 03:01 MyFTPFiles
```

Inside the folder it looks like this:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 myftpuser myftpuser  511704 Aug 30 03:01 file1.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 myftpuser myftpuser 1876608 Aug 30 03:01 file2.txt
```

If I try and work with the files in this folder I get the following error.

fopen(/mnt/2ndHDD/MyFTPFiles/file1.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied

I beleive my web app runs as www-data but the crontask runs as ubuntu

How can I set the file permissions so that ubuntu and www-data can read and write to the folder including newly added files by the ftpuser.

I have also added www-data and ubuntu to the myftpuser group

Many thanks in advance.